# Notify frontend Vue SPA if Stripe (iDEAL) charge is succeeded with Webhooks and Jobs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

So I'm building an webapp that has a shop with Laravel API and Vue as the frontend SPA.

I've been trying to use Strip to enable payments. So far, with the help of Stripe's documentation, I have been able to create a Source in the frontend. for iDEAL, Stripe highly suggests us to make use of webhooks to confirm whether a payment has succeeded. (I'm using Spatie/Laravel-Stripe-Webhook package) This is the current flow of my webapp:

Checkout.vue:

```
    checkout() {

        const sourceData = {
            type: 'ideal',
            amount: this.cart.total,
            currency: 'eur',
            owner: {
                name: this.name + ' ' + this.last_name,
                email: this.email,
            },
            metadata: {
                order: JSON.stringify(order),
                total_quantity: this.cart.total_quantity,
            },
            redirect: {
                return_url: 'http://example.test/order-confirmation',
            },
        }

        this.stripe.createSource(this.ideal, sourceData).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                console.log(error.message)
                this.error = error.message
            } else {
                stripeSourceHandler(result.source)
            }
        })

        const stripeSourceHandler = source => {
            document.location.href = source.redirect.url
        }

    },
```

1. After filling in billing address, emails etc. the user starts the payment.
2. User gets redirected to iDEAL payment page where they can authorize payment.
3. The Source is now created. Stripe sends `source.chargeable` webhook:

config/stripe-webhooks.php:

```
    'jobs' => [
        'source_chargeable' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\ProcessPaymentsJob::class,
        'charge_succeeded' => \App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks\ChargeSucceededJob::class,
    ],
```

ProcessPaymentsJob.php:

```
public function __construct(WebhookCall $webhookCall)
{
    $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
}

public function handle()
{
    $charge = $this->webhookCall->payload['data']['object'];

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

    $user = '';

    if(User::find(Auth::id())) {
        $user = $user->name;
    } else {
        $user = 'a guest';
    }

    $payment = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $charge['amount'],
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'source' => $charge['id'],
        'description' => 'New payment from '. $user,
        'metadata' => [
            'order' => $charge['metadata']['order'],
            'total_quantity' => $charge['metadata']['total_quantity'],
        ]
    ]);

}
```

4. User returns to `redirect[return_url]`
5. If all went well, Stripe should send charge.succeeded webhook:

ChargeSucceededJob.php:

```
public function __construct(WebhookCall $webhookCall)
{
    $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
}

public function handle()
{
$charge = $this->webhookCall->payload['data']['object'];

$order = Order::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::id() ?? null,
    'payment_id' => $charge['id'],
    'payment_method' => $charge['payment_method_details']['type'],
    'billing_email' => $charge['billing_details']['email'],
    'billing_name' => $charge['metadata']['name'],
    'billing_last_name' => $charge['metadata']['last_name'],
    'billing_address' => $charge['metadata']['address'],
    'billing_address_number' => $charge['metadata']['address_num'],
    'billing_postal_code' => $charge['metadata']['postal_code'],
    'billing_city' => $charge['metadata']['city'],
    'billing_phone' => strval($charge['billing_details']['phone']),
    'order' => json_decode($charge['metadata']['order']),
    'total_quantity' => (int) $charge['metadata']['total_quantity'],
    'billing_total' => $charge['amount'],
]);
}
```

This is all going well. However, I do not know how to notify the customer (on the frontend) that the order has been completed. In Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/best-practices), they explain how to retrieve the Source on the order confirmation page, but they do not explain how to retrieve the Charge, because this is what determines whether the whole order has been completed or not.

OrderConfirmation.vue:

```
    checkPaymentStatus() {
        this.stripe = Stripe(this.stripeKey)

        // After some amount of time, we should stop trying to resolve the order synchronously:
        const MAX_POLL_COUNT = 10;
        let pollCount = 0;

        let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)

        const pollForSourceStatus = async () => {
            const { source } = await this.stripe.retrieveSource({id: params.get('source'), client_secret: params.get('client_secret')})
            if (source.status === 'chargeable') {
                // Make a request to your server to charge the Source.
                // Depending on the Charge status, show your customer the relevant message.
            } else if (source.status === 'pending' && pollCount < MAX_POLL_COUNT) {
                // Try again in a second, if the Source is still `pending`:
                pollCount += 1;
                setTimeout(pollForSourceStatus, 1000);
            } else {
                // Depending on the Source status, show your customer the relevant message.
            }
        };

        pollForSourceStatus();
    }
```

How do I go from here? I am trying to notify the frontend when the Charge has been succeeded. My initial thought process was just to return the Order object, as I would do if it was a Controller, but if I understand correctly, the Job is running asynchronously, so I can't return data. I am also new to Jobs and Queues and stuff, I'm still trying to wrap my head around with it.

Another option I thought of is that I would poll requests from the frontend to the backend to request the last Order, but I have no idea how this would work and/or if this is a good solution.

Any help/tips/helpful resources would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

iDEAL payments are asynchronous, but they luckily do immediately notify you if the payment was successful or not.

When the iDEAL process is complete and your user is redirected to your site, Stripe [automatically appends some query parameters to the URL](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment#web-submit-payment). Meaning your users will be redirected to something like:

`https://example.com/checkout/complete?payment_intent=pi_123&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_123_secret_456&source_type=ideal`

The next step is to then retrieve the PaymentIntent and check on its [status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status), which you can do by either:

1. Retrieving the PaymentIntent on the client using stripe.js and the PaymentIntent client secret: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/retrieve_payment_intent
2. Retrieving the PaymentIntent on the server by sending an ajax request to your backend with the PaymentIntend ID: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve

If the status is `succeeded`, then the payment was completed and you can proceed from there.

Comment: Hmm okay. Just checked the docs out again and it appears I've been following their Sources API instead of their Payment Methods API. I'll have to go take a look at that again.